# program using task scheduler that echos user while running as admin

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm trying to create a program which echo's a current user.

As the program needs to be run as admin using the task scheduler the %username% always returns admin, NOT the user.

What I'm looking for in the end is a batch that echo's time stamp, user info and pc info every time a user logs on, off, locks, unlocks, switches user, ...

Comment: Administrator privileges are not required for any of the informations to output. It looks like the environment variables __DATE__, __TIME__, __USERNAME__ and __COMPUTERNAME__ provide all data you want to output. Please post the code you have already and add more details to get better help.

Comment: The code does need to run as admin, as the writing txt is stored in a secured server.

Comment: @echo off
cls
echo %date% %time% %username% %computername% >> \\******\_AD_Logon_Timestamp\%computername%.txt

Comment: this mini script allways returns as user admin as it's run as admin.

Comment: I think a directory on a server just used for small log files non containing really confidential data don't need to be so restrictive that nobody else than domain administrator has any access to it. The permissions on this specific directory on server could be set to allow everyone to create and modify existing files, but deny all other actions like creating subfolders, deleting files, or completely overwriting files. It is possible with NTFS permissions to restrict a directory in this manner. It might be worth thinking about this alternate approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue before, try using `whoami`

Answer (score 0):

The current user IS admin. Windows supports multiple users (although only 1 live one at a time). What you can do is query for users logged on and choose the interactive one.

Lists of potential users

```
wmic PATH Win32_SystemUsers get /format:List
wmic PATH WIN32_UserAccount get /format:List
wmic PATH WIN32_Account get /format:List
```

All the users logged on incl system accounts.
NB Administrators will have two logons - one as a limited user and one elevated.

```
wmic PATH Win32_LoggedOnUser get /format:List
```

To find info about the logon types

```
wmic PATH Win32_LogonSession get /format:list
```

List of logon types - you want 2.

```
LogonTypeData type: uint32Access type: Read-only


Numeric value that indicates the type of logon session.



Value

Meaning

0 
Used only by the System account.

 Interactive2 
Intended for users who are interactively using the machine, such as a user being logged on by a terminal server, remote shell, or similar process.

 Network3 
Intended for high-performance servers to authenticate clear text passwords. LogonUser does not cache credentials for this logon type.

 Batch4 
Intended for batch servers, where processes can be executed on behalf of a user without their direct intervention; or for higher performance servers that process many clear-text authentication attempts at a time, such as mail or web servers. LogonUser does not cache credentials for this logon type.

 Service5 
Indicates a service-type logon. The account provided must have the service privilege enabled.

 Proxy6 
Indicates a proxy-type logon.

 Unlock7 
This logon type is intended for GINA DLLs logging on users who are interactively using the machine. This logon type allows a unique audit record to be generated that shows when the workstation was unlocked. 

 NetworkCleartext8 
Preserves the name and password in the authentication packages, allowing the server to make connections to other network servers while impersonating the client. This allows a server to accept clear text credentials from a client, call LogonUser, verify that the user can access the system across the network, and still communicate with other servers.

 NewCredentials9 
Allows the caller to clone its current token and specify new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session has the same local identify, but uses different credentials for other network connections.

 RemoteInteractive10 
Terminal Services session that is both remote and interactive.

 CachedInteractive11 
Attempt cached credentials without accessing the network.

 CachedRemoteInteractive12
```